# Read and Write TIFF file in c using libtiff

Tags: c, image-processing, libtiff

This is the code that I wrote. It'll read from tiff file and then I'm trying to write to a different tiff file but getting black image in output.tiff. I've attached the input file. I'm adding all the necessary header in output file

```c
// Include necessary header files
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <tiffio.h>

// Main function
int main() {
    // Open the input and output TIFF files
    TIFF* tif_in = TIFFOpen("image.tiff", "rb");
    TIFF* tif_out = TIFFOpen("output.tiff", "w+");
    
    // Define a color map
    unsigned long cmap[2] = {0, 65535};
    
    // Check if input TIFF file opened successfully
    if (tif_in) {
        // Variables to store image properties
        uint32 width, height;
        uint16 bits_per_sample, samples_per_pixel;
        uint32 strip_size, tile_width, tile_height;
        uint8* strip_data;
        uint32 number_of_strips;
        uint16 compression_method;
        uint64* strip_offsets;
        uint64* strip_byte_counts;
        
        // Retrieve image properties from the input TIFF file
        TIFFGetField(tif_in, TIFFTAG_IMAGEWIDTH, &width);
        TIFFGetField(tif_in, TIFFTAG_IMAGELENGTH, &height);
        TIFFGetField(tif_in, TIFFTAG_BITSPERSAMPLE, &bits_per_sample);
        TIFFGetField(tif_in, TIFFTAG_SAMPLESPERPIXEL, &samples_per_pixel);
        TIFFGetField(tif_in, TIFFTAG_COMPRESSION, &compression_method);
        TIFFGetField(tif_in, TIFFTAG_STRIPOFFSETS, &strip_offsets);
        TIFFGetField(tif_in, TIFFTAG_STRIPBYTECOUNTS, &strip_byte_counts);
        
        // Set image properties for the output TIFF file
        TIFFSetField(tif_out, TIFFTAG_IMAGEWIDTH, width);
        TIFFSetField(tif_out, TIFFTAG_IMAGELENGTH, height);
        TIFFSetField(tif_out, TIFFTAG_PLANARCONFIG, PLANARCONFIG_CONTIG);
        TIFFSetField(tif_out, TIFFTAG_COMPRESSION, compression_method);
        TIFFSetField(tif_out, TIFFTAG_BITSPERSAMPLE, bits_per_sample);
        TIFFSetField(tif_out, TIFFTAG_SAMPLESPERPIXEL, samples_per_pixel);
        TIFFSetField(tif_out, TIFFTAG_STRIPOFFSETS, strip_offsets);
        TIFFSetField(tif_out, TIFFTAG_STRIPBYTECOUNTS, strip_byte_counts);
        TIFFSetField(tif_out, TIFFTAG_COLORMAP, cmap, cmap, cmap);
        
        // Calculate strip size and allocate memory for strip data
        strip_size = TIFFStripSize(tif_in);
        strip_data = (uint8*)malloc(strip_size);
        // Get the total number of strips in the image
        number_of_strips = TIFFNumberOfStrips(tif_in);
        
        // Print image properties
        printf("Strip size is %d\n", strip_size);
        printf("Number of strips are %d\n", number_of_strips);
        printf("Compression method is %d\n", compression_method);
        printf("Width: %d, Height: %d\n", width, height);
        
        // Read and write each strip from the input to the output TIFF file
        for (uint32 strip = 0; strip < number_of_strips; strip++) {
            TIFFReadEncodedStrip(tif_in, strip, strip_data, strip_size);
            TIFFWriteEncodedStrip(tif_out, strip, strip_data, strip_size);
        }
        
        // Close TIFF files and free allocated memory
        TIFFClose(tif_in);
        TIFFClose(tif_out);
        free(strip_data);
    } else {
        // Print error message if the input TIFF file failed to open
        printf("Failed to open the TIFF file.\n");
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

I want to read from input file and write to different file. Any help will be appreciated.

Input file:
[image: input file]

Comment: The color map should be 16-bit integers, not `long`. The first 0 is being interpreted as two 0s, most likely. But you also need to provide 256 integers in the color map, not just two. Oh, and you need to set the photometric interpretation tag: https://www.awaresystems.be/imaging/tiff/tifftags/photometricinterpretation.html

Comment: @CrisLuengo I tried but still only 1% is showing rest is black. I added a int map of size 256 which has number from 0-255. Also for the photometric interpretation I added PHOTOMETRIC_RGB. But still the result is not changing.

Comment: `int` is 32 bits on modern systems. Use `uint16`: `uint16 cmap[256]`.

Comment: Also, I see you're setting `TIFFTAG_STRIPOFFSETS` and `TIFFTAG_STRIPBYTECOUNTS`. Let the library figure these out. Especially the offsets, it seems dangerous to set those! Instead, set `TIFFTAG_ROWSPERSTRIP`, which must match the input's value in your case.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Can you tell me some resources to read about tiff

Comment: I'd start with the libTIFF tutorial to learn the basics of the library: https://libtiff.gitlab.io/libtiff/libtiff.html  , and the TIFF specification to understand the file format itself: https://web.archive.org/web/20180810205806/https://www.adobe.io/content/udp/en/open/standards/TIFF/_jcr_content/contentbody/download_1370394226/file.res/TIFFphotoshop.pdf ---- but TIFF is complex and it'll take some trial and error and some Googling to get the details right.